# Make JavaMail fast

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, smtp, jakarta-mail, restlet

I am trying to add email notification features to my Restlet server. I just learned today from Stackoverflow that Java Mail is synchronous.

So there are two obvious options: 1. use a really fast SMTP server 2. make it Asnyc

Well synchronously calling SMTP servers always introduce more delay. And since I'm simply using Java SE, no fancy EE stuff. What I am thinking about is initializing a new thread for sending the mail, however, things get much more complicated when I actually want to send the response from the mail server to web client to confirm mail is being processed by mail server, as I'll have to wait for thread to get a response.

Kinda confused right now, can anyone kindly offer suggestions on how I can do it with Java SE?

Server: Ubuntu Server 12.04

Answer (score 0):

Java SE offers concurrency functionality for delegating work into seperate threads see [java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html)